# How can I add menuItem from an array?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

this is my array

```html
const cct =cca.table.field.split(',');
console.log(cct);
```

How can I use it to add menuItem for my SelectInput

```html
  <SelectInput value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleDropDownChange}            
            maxHeight={200}
            
            floatingLabelFixed={true}
            >
            {myarray}
        </SelectInput>
```

I tried to do it this way

```html
    const cct = cca.table.field.split(',');
    const items= [];
    cct.forEach(element => {
      cct.push(<MenuItem key={element.Key} value={element.Key} primaryText={element.Value} />);
    });
    console.log(cct);
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: And,you may change forEach to map, forEach has no return data.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you're trying to use the Material UI [Select](https://material-ui.com/api/select/) and [MenuItem](https://material-ui.com/api/menu-item/) components.

The following should work:

```
render() {
  const cct = cca.table.field.split(',');

  const menuItems = cct.map(item => (
    <MenuItem key={element.Key} value={element.Key}>{item.Value}</MenuItem>
  ));

  return (
    <Select 
      value={this.state.value}
      onChange={this.handleDropDownChange}
    >
      {menuItems}
    </Select>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the input to the push method as string by enclosing the

```
<MenuItem key={element.Key} value={element.Key} primaryText={element.Value} />
```

in **" "** (Double quotes)

This would work :

```
const cct = cca.table.field.split(',');
const items= [];
cct.forEach(element => {
  cct.push("<MenuItem key={element.Key} value={element.Key} primaryText={element.Value} />");
});
console.log(cct);
```